# Changes in the transition matrix of a Markov chain

Tags: reference-request, stochastic-processes, markov-chains

In most or all Markov chain theories that I know of assumes that the transition matrix does not change over time. But what if certain changes are expected to occur at certain times in the transition matrix? I would much appreciate if some one could suggest me a text book or explain me what happens when changes in the transition matrix occurs since it will affect many aspects of the usual Markov chain theorems that I currently know of. Thank you

Comment: The property you are thinking of is called stationarity or time-homogeneity of the Markov chain / process (not to be confused with a stationary measure). There are many books written on the subject, but which one is right for you depends on your background. Are you comfortable with continuous time / continuous space M.C.? Do you have measure theory? Brownian motion?

Comment: @snarski Is continuous space MC necessary for this? Can't I consider the discrete case for the moment? I do not have a good knowledge on those topics however I can go through all of it.

Comment: @snarski I have to point out that I am interested in the case when matrix is not time homogeneous